# Make a MySQL query fail by value based decision

Tags: mysql, validation, error-handling

I am using a MySQL query like the following that gathers and calculates quantities from some source tables and then inserts/updates that many rows to another table of the same MySQL 5.6 database:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (quantity, id) 
(
    SELECT my_quantity, my_id FROM 
    ( 
      SELECT my_id, (one_quantity-COALESCE(more_quantity,0)) my_quantity, ... FROM
        /* Some very complicated sub-query*/
    ) t
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=my_quantity
```

My problem now is that my_quantity can contain negative value(s) because it is the result of the subtraction of two columns in the sub-query. Negative values should normally never happen since the base value should always be >= the subtracted value. However if someone populated the tables the totally wrong way this still could happen and in that case I don't want the INSERT or UPDATE to be executed at all.

So is there a way to cause some kind of (custom) error to make the entire query to decease in case of the unlikely occurance of one or more negative values in my_quantity? Or do I need to use a server stored procedure in that case?

Comment: Could you just mark my_quantity as UNSIGNED?

Comment: Yes, I could do so. Never tried this... does writing a negative value to an unsigned cause an error? Or is the value just clipped or ignored?

Comment: It depends on SQL Mode: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html . For InnoDB it will through exception by default. But you may configure to clip invalid values as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended implementing a server stored procedure returning a 1 or 0 as a result in case of success or failure. Also the SSP takes care of not changing the database if negative values appeared using a temporary table.

The procedure became a pretty complicated beast but we couldn't find an easier solution (especially no reliable configration independant solution without a SSP).